# How to parse XML in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, plsql

I have following xml struct in pl/sql:

```
<struct>
  <member>
    <name>CODE</name>
    <value>
      <integer>0</integer>
    </value>
  </member>
  <member>
    <name>MSG</name>
    <value>
      <string>Some message</string>
    </value>
  </member>
</struct>
```

How can i extract values in path /member/value/some_type using text in name tag?
I mean something like this:

```
extract('//member/value/*[filter name tag = CODE]').getStringValue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `local-name()`

XPath should be,

```
//member/value/*[local-name()='CODE']
```

### Example:

1. `//member/value/*[local-name()='integer']`
2. `//member/value/*[local-name()='string']`

### Result:

1. 0
2. Some message

## UPDATE:

In this case, you XPath should be

```
//member[*='CODE']/*/*
//member[*='MSG']/*/*
```

### Result:

1. 0
2. Some message

Comment: Using your examples i can filter only integer/string and so on. But i need filter using //member/name value

Comment: Now i get right filter, but wrong value - <integer>0</integer> instead of 0

Comment: @DigitalGod: Xpath is `//member[*='CODE']/*/*/text()`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you don't treat databases as ETL (extract,transform,load) tools.  What you want to do is pass this XML file to a separate program that uses XPath and process it that way.  Databases are only supposed to store data.  In fact I have spent the past 5 months removing "exotic " code like this that made an Oracle database take 72+ hours to insert 400k rows.  So again offset this to xpath

The query will look almost identical to your command above

Comment: In the current situation, I can only use stored procedures.